# Howto Extract Integers from a String with a Slash?

Tags: java, string, extract

```
String value = "30/90"
// Extracting 30 to a and 90 to b 
int a = 30;
int b = 90
```

How do I extract the "30" and "90" as the example above.
So the slash will indicate where "a" and "b" are.

Comment: Split at "/". Check out the String class. And show more research effort :(

Comment: Keyser, It's not easy to find without knowing about "Split"

Comment: You can always check out the String methods: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: "Extract String by Slash Java" -Google

Comment: Try 'string manipulation java', [Manipulating Characters in a String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/manipstrings.html), & the [methods of `String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#method_summary).  Then try writing some code to experiment.

Comment: Actually, it is @user1621988. All you need to know is what class you're using, then skim through the documentation. If you don't know about the documentation, that's when it gets tricky (but googling java classes brings them up front).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

split the string with `/` as a delimiter using **[String#Split("/"):](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)**:

```
            String value = "30/90";
            int a = Integer.parseint(value.split("/")[0]);
            int b= Integer.parseInt(value.split("/")[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Split the String by the `/`s and parse the resulting Strings as integers.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String value = "30/90";
        // Extracting 30 to a and 90 to b 
        String[] values = value.split("/");
        int a = Integer.parseInt(values[0]);
        int b = Integer.parseInt(values[1]);
        System.out.println(a + " " + b);
    }
}
```